# Need help posting to my own wall in Facebook with PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

The code below is not working for some reason:

```
require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'working_app_id',
  'secret' => 'working_secret'
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

print $token; // token shows.

$attachment = array
 (
 'access_token'=>$token,
 'message' => 'This is where the message will go.',
 'name' => 'Name Text',
 'link' => 'http://www.website.com',
 'description' => 'Description text.'
 );

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);

exit;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

When I print the token, it appears to be a real token.  I just have no idea what I could be doing wrong.  All I want to do is post a very simple status update to my own page.

I don't know why I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm banging my head against the wall on this one because it should just be so simple to post a quick little status update to my wall in Facebook from PHP.

Note: The App Type I created to get my appID and secret was a "Website".

Comment: try look those description! [i wrote answer here][1]!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629332/how-post-on-facebooks-timeline-via-cron

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer, it appears that you are using the wrong method to get your access token.

[Howto use FB Graph to post a message on a feed (wall)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783582/howto-use-fb-graph-to-post-a-message-on-a-feed-wall)